# Licensing scheme for client application that accesses web service

Tags: web-services, licensing

I'm currently in the decision of under what license I should release a .NET client software that accesses our web service. The best way to describe my situation would be like Dropbox, as they have a client software that simply allows users to access their web service.

I'm not sure whether the best decision is to go open source on this to promote growth, support, etc or to keep the source closed with some  to help reduce the number of non-official clients running specifically meant to misuse / abuse the webservice backend.

(If it helps any the client software will be computing and sending data to a backend, so tampering of the submitted data would be best kept at a minimum.)

Pros, cons, and suggestions are welcome

Comment: +1 for interesting, clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't there a way to work with sessions in a webservice? If you could implement that, you could make the users of the client login first to your webservice (via the client application), and then only make the functionalities available after a successful login. That way, should you decide to release an open source version, you will greatly reduce the risk of rogue clients already.

As for the decision whether to go open source or not, that's entirely up to you, but I don't think the choice should affect security.

Comment: Well if it was open source one could change the client so that instead of submitting, for example, hashes of different numbers it could instead send random 64 bit data that appeared to be a hash so it could appear faster that it would otherwise. Which would be harder if the source wasn't easily available (right? :)

Comment: @BraunShedd Well you are right, but if you are describing a brute force attack, you'll need a webservice that draws a whole lot of attention :) I don't think many (bad) hackers are interested in just breaking random software... On a side note, could you explain with more detail what you mean with "it would be bad if the data is tampered with"? What could the client do that is bad for your webservice?

Comment: Well the service I'm referring to involves paying users for rending CG scenes for however many GZ/h they contribute. My worry is users attempting to change settings of the render scenes to send in images similar to the expected output but quicker to compute (reducing anti-aliasing, etc)

Comment: @BraunShedd wow, that's quite a complex project... I'm afraid you'll have a lot more obstacles to overcome than the one your question is about... good luck :) Oh, and since you mentioned payment, that makes the open-source option completely impossible. You'll always have cheaters when there's money involved, a bit stupid to leave the door open for them.

Comment: My point exactly :). Open source or not though, the client still won't be trusted to submit legit data, at which point you use double renders from two different machines, and on and on... :P

Comment: @BraunShedd Too complicated for me :) you must be a good programmer if you can build an entire render farm...